# displaying nested JSON with react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an object like:

```
export const contact = {
  _id: "1",
  first:"John",
  name: {
    first:"John",
    last:"Doe"
  },
  phone:"555",
  email:"john@gmail.com"
};
```

I am reading it like

```
return (
 <div>
   <h1>List of Contact</h1>
   <h1>{this.props.contact._id}</h1>
 </div>
```

)

in this scenario I am getting expected output.

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>List of Contact</h1>
    <h1>{this.props.contact.name.first}</h1>
  </div>
)
```

But when I read the nested property I am getting error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined

How to read these king of nested objects in react? Here is [my source](https://github.com/bhavankris/testing1/blob/master/src/pages/contact-list-page.js)

Comment: Your post says `contact` is the variable but you code uses `contacts`.

Comment: in have connected through redux store and receiving contact as contacts.And i am able to retrieve value of _id

Comment: Can you edit your post to correct the typo then?

Comment: have changed it

Comment: There might be something more to it than your snippet of code reveals. I have created http://jsbin.com/firufoc/edit?js,output and it appears to work with your code

Comment: @BhavanKris this data is always present or you are fetching this from server then showing in ui ?

Comment: it did not work.it works when i have the object initialised like your snippet. @user2340824

Comment: i have separate object like data File. and here in my code i have connected with redux for data handling.and from redux store i am getting data. I am able to get the value contact._id but not able to pull contact.name.first. @MayankShukla

Comment: that means you are not returning the default value, to slove that issue simply put the check like this: `return (
  <div>
    <h1>List of Contact</h1>
    <h1>{this.props.contact.name && this.props.contact.name.first}</h1>
  </div>)`

Comment: when i am using {this.props.contact.name} it works.{this.props.contact.name && this.props.contact.name.first} this did not work. ill share the git hub repo of the code https://github.com/bhavankris/testing1/blob/master/src/pages/contact-list-page.js @MayankShukla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things you need to address here:

1. this is your `contacts-data` and i don't see any `first` property within the `name` object:

```js
export const contacts = {
  "name": "mkyong",
  "age": 30,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
    "city": "New York"
  },
  "phoneNumber": [{
    "type": "home",
    "number": "111 111-1111"
  }, {
    "type": "fax",
    "number": "222 222-2222"
  }]
};
```

2. You are calling `this.props.fetchContacts();` on `componentDidMount`, hence in the first `render` call the `state` is still empty, the `action` call and the `reducer` will pass new props or change the state then you get to the second `render` call and that's the moment you have the data ready for use.
   So you should check for the existing of the data before you try to use it. one way is to just conditionally render it (of course there are better ways to do it, this is just to make a point):

```js
  render() {
    const { contacts } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List of Contacts</h1>
        <h2>{contacts && contacts.name && contacts.name.first
          //still getting error. "this.props.contacts.name" alone works
          }</h2>
        <h2>{contacts && contacts.address && contacts.address.city}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

3. You are trying to use `this.props.contact.name.first` is that a typo? shouldnt it be `contacts` instead of `contact`?

**EDIT**:
As a followup for your comment, as a general rule in JavaScript (or any other language for that manner) you should always check the existence reference of an object before you are trying to access it's properties.
As for your use case you can use `defaultProps` if you must have a value to render or you can even simplify the scheme of your data.
This is much simpler to manage:

```
export const contacts =
    {
        "fName": "mkyong",
        "lName": "lasty",
        "age": 30,
        "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "homeNumber": "111 111-1111",
        "faxNumber": "222 222-2222"
    };
```

Than this:

```
export const contacts = 
  {"name": "mkyong",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
        "city": "New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "111 111-1111"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "222 222-2222"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: 2 worked out  i am able to get the output.is there a better way to do it?